# Passing parameters into browser.executeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, types, protractor

How do I pass in parameters into `browser.executeScript`

```
  static sortableDragAndDropByClassName(dragElementClassName: string, dropElementClassName: string) {
    return browser.executeScript(function () {
      console.log(dragElementClassName);
      console.log(dropElementClassName);
    });
  }
```

Gives me the following error message:

```
- Failed: javascript error: dragElementClassName is not defined
```

My test:

```
 Helpers.sortableDragAndDropByClassName('page-row-option-item-1', 'page-row-option-item-0').then(() => {

 ...

 });
```

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61226704/3001761)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass those variables as arguments and access them like so.

```
return browser.executeScript(function () {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
}, dragElementClassName, dropElementClassName);
```